# How to go backwards in an FTP connection : PYTHON

Tags: python, ftp

```
            ftp.cwd("TXNnIGZvbGRlcg==/")
            file = open('msg.txt', 'rb')
            file.storbinary('STOR msg.txt', file)
            file.close
```

So just a quick answer I need... the code shows a msg being saved in the base64 folder in the FTP server, however in earlier code, I've already said:

```
if name != "":
ftp.mkd(name)
ftp.cwd(name)
```

So it's already navigated somewhere, but I need help on finding the command on how to go back a directory.

something like

ftp.goback()

Or something.

Comment: Take a look at this question to see if it pays your bill. The main idea is to remember the directory you were before,.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22581812/going-through-ftp-directories-in-python :)

Comment: I was actually looking at that, but then I was thinking, how would you import it into my code, since I put it in just before it goes to the base64 folder, but then it says that it doesn't exist.

Comment: I'll try fixing the folder name

Comment: Nope, it just says it doesn't exist

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can try something like this.

```
ftp.cwd("TXNnIGZvbGRlcg==/")
file = open('msg.txt', 'rb')
ftp.storbinary('STOR msg.txt', file)
file.close()
ftp.cwd("../")
```